# Displaying text from a textfile using strtok_s

Tags: c++, string, vector, text-files, strtok

I am beginner in C++, I am trying to put text into a vector from a textfile by using tokens with strtok_s.

I can get just one text pushed back and displayed in the vector and I sure that there are some problems in my coding.

Here are the codes :

```
    std::vector<char> myVector;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("E:/C++/Projects/Textfile project/Textfile project/class_data.txt", ios_base::in); 
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            myReadFile >> output;
        }

    }
    myReadFile.close();

    char* token = NULL;
    char* context = NULL;
    char delims[] = " ,\t\n";


    token = strtok_s(output, delims, &context);

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (token != NULL) 
        {
            myVector.push_back(token);
            token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << myVector[i] << endl;
    }
```

I am trying to get the text out of the text file, separate it into individual parts and put them into a vector of chars.

Can anyone tell me what mistakes I have done ? And sorry for not professional coding, I am a high school student trying to learn C++.

The edited codes, which work :

```
std::vector<std::string> myVector;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("E:/C++/Projects/Textfile project/Textfile project/class_data.txt", ios_base::in); 
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            myReadFile >> output;

            char* token = NULL;
            char* context = NULL;
            char delims[] = " ,\t\n";

            token = strtok_s(output, delims, &context);

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                myVector.push_back(token);
                token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);
            }
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
        cout << myVector[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Show some text from `class_data.txt`

Comment: class_data.txt ...' A00529154 76 79 85 91 75 80 90 56 58
A00656624 79 85 0  86 86 76 51 89 92
A02507691 47 94 92 49 77 72 25 25 95
A00612352 41 82 90 58 87  0 50 98 80
A04012435 91 50 78 68 70 60 42 74 85
A00654400 47 94 89 75 80 76  0 71 83
A00577109 44 88 84 86 89 88 99 100 90
A00580920 41 82 80 90 89 97 93 84 86
A04028610 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  
A04063494 90 90 90 90 70 90 90 90 90 '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the vector of objects of type char `std::vector<char> myVector;` you need to define a vector of objects of type `std::string`

```
std::vector<std::string> myVector;
```

This statement

```
myVector.push_back(token);
```

is invalid because you are trying to push a pointer instead of a character.

Also the if statement inside the while loop

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (token != NULL) 
    {
        myVector.push_back(token);
        token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);

    }
}
```

is superflouos and can be removed

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    myVector.push_back(token);
    token = strtok_s(NULL, delims, &context);

}
```

Also take into account that in this loop

```
    while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
        myReadFile >> output;
    }
```

object output is always overwritten. You should combine this loop with the loop of splitting output into tokens. Otherwise you are dealing with the last record of the file.

Comment: thank you, I will try to fix everything that you wrote down, I will get back to to you @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: Hi @Vlad from Moscow. You helped me before, could you help me again, I have a different kind of issue this time. Could you take a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/23233993/… or stackoverflow.com/questions/23189706/… please, and could you tell me how to do it properly ?

Comment: @Uther Pendragon The references you showed can not be used.

Comment: Hi @Vlad from Moscow . Sorry about that .Here is the correct reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233993/how-to-declare-a-font-variable-properly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189706/how-to-use-font-as-a-variable

Comment: @Uther Pendragon I have wrote my answer to the post about Font in C++/CLI.