# How to use Font as a variable?

Tags: c++, fonts, clr

I would have a quick question :
What do I have to include into a visual C++/CLR project to be able to use  `Font^` ?
I have tried to create a ref class, something like this :

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(FontConverter))]
public ref class Font sealed : public MarshalByRefObject, 
    ICloneable, ISerializable, IDisposable
```

(got it from here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1 )

I am working on a project were I have to be able to print something, so my coding is really similiar to something like this : 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp)

I tried to use a namespace for the `Font^`, something like this :

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Printing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

OR I tried to use a dll. file in order to be able to use a Font^ as a variable (specifically  `#using <System.Drawing.dll`>

But none seemed to work out ...
So what I would need is to use `Font^` as a variable, something like this :

```
Font^ printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
```

Could anyone suggest a way to allow Font^ to be used, because in my error list it says that Font^ printFont is unidentified.

P.S. I am a beginner in c++, I really do not know how to use the Font^ as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to have:

```
System::Drawing::Font ^printFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 10);
```

instead of :

```
Font ^printFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 10);
```