# How to declare a Font variable properly?

Tags: fonts, c++-cli

I would have a quick question :
Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this line :

```
Font ^printFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 10);
```

My compiler says "Identifier 'printFont' is unidentified".
I also have the namespaces and the dll file included :

```
 #using <System.Drawing.dll>
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Drawing::Text;
    using namespace System::Drawing::Printing;
```

PS. Sorry for not pro coding, but I did not take any University level programming in C++/CLR.

Edited :

```
private: System::Void testCorrection_PrintPage_1(System::Object^  sender, System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs^  e) {

float linesPerPage = 0;
float yPos = 0;
int count = 0;
float leftMargin = (float)e->MarginBounds.Left;
float topMargin = (float)e->MarginBounds.Top;
String^ line = nullptr; 

Font ^printFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 10); // error is :" IntelliSense:identifier 'PrintFont' is undefined "
SolidBrush ^myBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black);

StreamReader^ streamToPrint;

// Calculate the number of lines per page.
linesPerPage = e->MarginBounds.Height / printFont->GetHeight(e->Graphics);
line = streamToPrint->ReadLine();

// Iterate over the file, printing each line.
while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = streamToPrint->ReadLine()) != nullptr)) {
        yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont->GetHeight(e->Graphics));
        e->Graphics->DrawString(line, printFont, myBrush, leftMargin, yPos, gcnew StringFormat);
        count++;
        line = streamToPrint->ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post a *minimal, "compilable"† code* example that reproduces the error? Six lines in a void are not enough for that. †I mean, with no error *other* than this one.

Comment: Hi @Medinoc , I edited my coding. I displayed the whole section about the Font, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Never mind I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have directive

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

then you can write simply

```
Font ^printFont = gcnew Font("Arial", 10);
```

I think the problem is that you did not add reference to `System.Drawing` to the project